# rich:datascroller not working with rich:datatable on Internet Explorer

Tags: java, jsf

I have rich:datascroller as header and footer to rich:datatable in JSF.It works well when click on datascroller to page navigation when run on google chrome but when same run on internet explorer doesnt show data in datatable when f5 is pressed then it shows the data in datatable.

Comment: could you show us your code?

Comment: <rich:datascroller align="left" for="MenucategorymstGrid" maxPages="100" fastControls="hide" style="width:900px"
       page="#{MenucategorymstListView.scrollerPage}" id="sc2" reRender="sc1,searchpanel" ajaxSingle="false">

Answer (score 0):

In my case was same plugin added that generates error when I tried click to change to other view. I reset browser's configuration to uninstall all pluggins and the navegation between pages back to work.

P.S: Sorry my poor English :-)